# How to get only the latest value in the shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I am a beginner.

My log file will generate values every 30 seconds. Because the log file is generated from another system and I cannot synchronize the time with that system.
The purpose of the script file is run every second to get the latest value in the 2nd column when it is generated and update on the system time.
But i'm stuck, if the log file stop before 08:04:00, my script file keeps updating the final value on the system time.
My question is: How to do when the log file stopped, the script file will no longer update that last value ?

My shell script

```
!/bin/bash
prodStartTime="080000"
prodEndTime="080400"
TS_LOG=/home/uat/log/TL.log
currentTime=`date +"%H%M%S"`
if [[ $currentTime > $prodStartTime && $currentTime < $prodEndTime ]]
then
    a=$(tail -1 $TS_LOG | awk '{print $2}')
    b=$(echo $a | awk 'BEGIN{FIELDWIDTHS="2 2 2"}{print $1,$2,$3}' | sed 's; ;\:;g')
    if [[ $a != $currentTime ]]
    then
        date +%T -s $b
    fi
sleep 1
else
    exit 1
fi
```

My log file:

```
-- 13:55:15.265
--BC=[391]  135515
-- 16:55:15.265
--BC=[391]  **165515**
```

Comment: You say you cannot synchronize the time between both systems, which sort of implies you cannot access system1 from system2 and vice versa. So how do you get access to this log-file? Normally when you synchronize time, you use `ntp`, did you check this out?

Comment: You actually introduce much more time-issues due to this script. You call various binaries (`awk`, `sed`, `date`) which all add up on time adding actually a time-offset between both systems. I'm fairly convinced that if you synchronise both systems properly ones, you are fine for various months.

Comment: @kvantour: Because the log file will be sent from another company's system and have a different time zone. When my system receives this file it will run the trading commands. But because of different time zones, the outgoing transaction is delayed. And of course they won't let us sync to their ntp server so I came up with this as a temporary solution.

Comment: What do you mean with _if the logfile stopped_? I'm under the impression that you receive a copy of that file every 30 seconds?

Comment: @kvantour: Value will be sent every 30 seconds. And I only need to get the value between 8:00:00 - 08:04:00.  And when that system stops sending before 08:04:00 my script file will continue to update old value.

Comment: How accurate do you want your synchronisation to be? What is the DELTA_T you expect between two servers. At the moment it is possible to have 1sec difference

Comment: Currently i think 1 second is enough because the value will be sent after every 30 seconds.